# Trying to detect monitor

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get the monitor in order to check if is off or not.

Before checking with `GetDevicePowerState`, I'm trying to retrieve monitor in this way:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    POINT* p = new POINT;
    p->x=0;
    p->y=0;
    HMONITOR* monitor = MonitorFromPoint(p,DWORD.MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But it continually gives me:

```
main.cpp `MonitorFromPoint' undeclared (first use this function)
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You are writing C code, not C++ code.

Comment: But he is `using namespace std;`! This **must** be C++ ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems, but none of them should cause the error message you're seeing. Here's code with some corrections, and a little more added to show at least some kind of result from the test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    POINT p{ 0, 0 };
    HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromPoint(p, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL);

    if (monitor == NULL) 
        std::cout << "No monitor found for point (0, 0)\n";
    else {
        MONITORINFOEX info;
        info.cbSize = sizeof(info);

        GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &info);
        std::cout << "Monitor: " << info.szDevice << "\n";
    }
}
```

I've tested this with both VC++ 2013 and MinGW 4.8.1, and in both cases it's compiled and run without any problems, producing:

```
Monitor: \\.\DISPLAY1
```

...as its output in both cases.

Comment: hi! i try to compile your code but i get this error: main.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':

main.cpp:6: error: expected primary-expression before "p"
main.cpp:6: error: expected `;' before "p"
main.cpp:7: error: `p' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:7: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
main.cpp:7: error: `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:7: error: `MonitorFromPoint' undeclared (first use this function)

make.exe: *** [main.o] Error 1

Execution terminated

Comment: @JackTurky: Perhaps you're using a defective (or just ancient) version of Windows.h that's missing declarations of the relevant structures, functions, etc? As noted, I compiled and ran the code with current versions of both VC++ and MinGW.

Comment: i'm using windows xp pro sp3. do you thing is defective?